# Any static binary for x86-64 that can download over https

Tags: android, download, https

I'm looking for any binary ( like wget/curl ) that could download over https , is statically built and for x86-64 architecture.
I'm looking for a way to download from https on my android emulator, it needs to run from terminal.
( I also tried setting up python so i could download using requests but i failed miserably , i'm looking for any solution no matter what it is )
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't you want an *arm* binary to run on an Android emulator? If you want Linux utilities on Android it may be easier to install a Linux distribution in a chroot (search this site, I'm pretty sure it's been covered before).

Comment: Well no my architecture is x86-64 , not ARM and the wget you get , the only binary that worked for me , is the one i found using static-get :  
http://javier.io/blog/en/2015/06/23/static-get.html  ( this pretty much means that my problem is solved , thanks a lot anyways )